# First time XML user, what does this error mean?

Tags: java, xml, spring

It's the first time I'm using XML in java and I would like some assistance with my code. I can't see where I'm wrong. thanks.

What I am trying to do is understand the Spring Framework.

Here is the code:

```
public class Student
{

    public Student(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // VARIABLES DECLARATION
    private String name = null;
}

public class Controller
{
    public Controller(Student student)
    {
        this.student = student;
    }
    public void PrintName()
    {
        System.out.println(""+student.getName());
    }

    public Student getStudent()
    {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student)
    {
        this.student = student;
    }   
    // VARIABLES DECLARATION
    private Student student;
}



public class LearnXML
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO code application logic here
        ApplicationContext factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Student.xml");
        Controller contr = (Controller) factory.getBean("application");
        contr.PrintName();
    }

    public void setController(Controller controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
    }   
    private Controller controller;
}
```

My XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="student" class="domain.Student">
        <constructor-arg value="Ovidiu"   />
    </bean>
    <bean id="brain" class="controller.Controller">
        <constructor-arg ref="student"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="application" class="learnxml.LearnXML">
        <property name="controller" ref="brain"/>   
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My errors:

```
    Dec 25, 2012 5:34:02 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@dd0099: startup date [Tue Dec 25 17:34:02 EET 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 25, 2012 5:34:03 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Student.xml]
Dec 25, 2012 5:34:03 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5ceeb4a3: defining beans [student,brain,application]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: learnxml.LearnXML cannot be cast to controller.Controller
    at learnxml.LearnXML.main(LearnXML.java:25)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means exactly what it says:

`learnxml.LearnXML cannot be cast to controller.Controller`

You have a `LearnXML` object:

```
<bean id="application" class="learnxml.LearnXML">
    <property name="controller" ref="brain"/>   
</bean>
```

And are trying to cast it to a `Controller` object:

```
Controller contr = (Controller) factory.getBean("application");
```

`getBean()` is returning an `Object` rather than a specific type due to the inherent nature of the task at hand; it's using reflection to instantiate any type from the xml so it doesn't know what the type is at compile time. At runtime if you attempt to cast that `Object` to something it's not ... you get that exception.

**Edit to Add:**

In case it isn't obvious, it appears you're really wanting to do:

```
LearnXML lXML = (LearnXML) factory.getBean("application");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting here `factory.getBean("application");`

LearnXML type object but you are casting it to Controller

If you want to get Controller use brain like this

```
Controller contr = (Controller) factory.getBean("brain");
```

Answer (score 1):

Controller contr = (Controller) factory.getBean("application");
You cant typecast LearnXML object to Controller object

Try this.
LearnXML learnXml= (LearnXML ) factory.getBean("application");
learnXml.getController().PrintName();

Answer (score 1):

Change your code below line

> LearnXML learnXML= (LearnXML) factory.getBean("application");